# React - Using a Callback function to pass data from Child to Parent

Tags: reactjs, callback

I am currently making a simple Dropdown menu in which I want to pass certain state values to its parent so that the parent will fetch data from the backend.

I have written a callback function in my parent function that I am passing as a prop to the child; however, I am not getting any output when I log the change on the console, hence I don't think I am using the callback properly.
This is my dropdown menu:

```
class Dropdown extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  
    this.state = {
      headerTitle: this.props.title,
      teams: this.props.teams,

    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  handleClick(teamID) {
      this.setState({
        headerTitle: this.state.teams[teamID].name
      })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="btn-group w-100 d-flex">
        <button type="button" className="btn-success w-100 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" onChange={this.props.handleTeam}>
          {this.state.headerTitle}
        </button>
        <ul className="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable w-100" role="menu">
          {this.state.teams.map((team) => {
            return (
              <li>
                <a href="#/game-pred" className="dropdown-item d-flex justify-content-center" onClick={() => this.handleClick(team.id)} >{team.name}</a>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my parent:

```
class GamePrediction extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      teams: [],
      count: 0,
    };
    this.handleTitleChange = this.handleTitleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleTitleChange(newTitle) {
    if (this.state.count == 2){
      this.setState({
        teams: [newTitle,this.state.teams[1]]
      })
    }
    else if (this.state.count == 1) {
      this.setState({
        teams: [this.state.teams[0],newTitle],
        count: 2
      })
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
      teams: teams.push(newTitle),
      count: this.state.count + 1
    })
    }
    console.log("Change!",this.state.teams,this.state.count)
  } 
  render() {
        
    return (
      <div className="button-group w-100 d-flex" >
        <Dropdown title="Team 1" teams={teams} handleTeam={this.handleTitleChange} ref="team1"/>
        <Dropdown title="Team 2" teams={teams} ref="team2"/>
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It should also be noted that there are two dropdown menus from which the user can select one team for each dropdown, if that helps.

Comment: You are using `onChange` on the button instead of `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

A `<button>` has an `onClick`, not an `onChange`,

so you probably want to change this

```
<button type="button" className="btn-success w-100 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" onChange={this.props.handleTeam}>
```

to this

```
<button type="button" className="btn-success w-100 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" onClick={this.props.handleTeam}>
```

Also I see that your `handleTitleChange(newTitle)` accepts a `newTitle` param, you can pass that param like this

```
<button type="button" className="btn-success w-100 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" onClick={() => this.props.handleTeam('My new Title')}>
```

Comment: I'm already using the onClick on the button to change the button name, but I guess I could show what team they selected in a different way.